# MySQL: Where 'Not in' not working for strings

Tags: mysql, sql

i am a begginer in sql but i cant figure out what i am doing wrong with the 'categoria_contato' field.

This is the code:

```
SELECT categoria_contato, left(createdate,7), COUNT(*) 
FROM hs_contacts 
WHERE LEFT(createdate,7) >'2019-09' 
    AND categoria_contato NOT IN ('Field Sales', 'CrossX')
GROUP BY categoria_contato, LEFT(categoria_contato,7);
```

The results:

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Your `LEFT()` in the `GROUP BY` needs to be on the same column as the `LEFT()` in your `SELECT` list

Comment: @SeanBright Good catch! But also the `WHERE` clause should filter the rows in spite of the bad grouping (see rows 10 and 12), so there's another issue here, too. I'm thinking trailing whitespace or hidden unicode characters.

Comment: is `categoria_contato` a mandatory column ?

Comment: right, it can be extra white space

Comment: It was hidden unicode characters! Thanks Guy!

Why i need to change the left in the group ??

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

A good practice is have ID instead of text for the keys. 
For you example you can have 'categoria_contato' and 'categoria_contato_id' and filter by ID.
May not solve you current problem, but it gonna solve a lot of problems in the future becouse, for example,  it dont depend on special characters.

Comment: Maybe, but it's not an answer

Comment: i think it is becouse text is not good for filter as id. If you change the text with ID it's solved.